# use async/await instead of (.then)

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to replace .then with async/await

here is my code

```
    export const loginUser = (userData) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        await axios.post('/api/users/login', userData);
        // Save to localStorage
        const {token} = res.data;
        // Save token to local storage
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
        // Set token to Auth header
        setAuthToken(token);
        // Decode to get user data
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        // set current user
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
        })
    }
};
```

and then this is the error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of
>   undefined ▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: You haven't assigned `res` in your code. Try something like ```await const res = axios.post...```

Comment: it would be `const res = await axios.post(...);` then `const {token} = await res.data`

Comment: thanks !! it works !!